# COPY and PASTE to/from Excel and MVC web application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have tested both Google Docs and Microsoft Office live and seen that is possible with both tools to do two way copy and paste with Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V with Excel document running in my windows based machine.

This is also a requirement for our new web application we are defining the architecture right now.

We plan to use ASP.NET MVC 3 and I am not sure if there is any grid out there able to handle this feature. The interesting thing is that neither Google docs or Office live requires any plugin to be installed on the client and does not display any security warning so it looks like Javascript is actually able to access to the windows clipboard ( set / get ).

To find a nice MVC editable grid is also a big challenge, something I could move around with the arrow keys and simply edit any cell...

Has anybody sorted out anything similar before? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

We used [ExtJS](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/) on one of our MVC applications to do this kind of thing. They have some pretty powerful and flexible grids that sound like the kind of thing you're looking for.

[ExtJS Website](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/)

Comment: Hi Jamie, I have been thinking about ExtJS 4 before and was/am very tempted by it. Do you actually do this kind of copy/paste with extJs grid already? How do you integrate it with MVC? do you use always their grids in your views or only in some pages? It could work and I would like it but want to make sure it integrates smoothly with ASP.NET MVC concept and server side engine. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Davide. Our front end team worked with the ExtJS side of things more than I did. What we did do was use ExtJS as our actual View layer. We didn't have standard MVC views but passed all information between ExtJS configurations and our controllers. We used ExtJS components in every page whether it was a grid or a chart. The entire app was based around information management. (It was a statistical analysis app for a portfolio management company)